# How to save a list of objects locally in a simple way

Tags: flutter, dart

So I am building an app and in it I type in a list of names as objects. But when i close the app they are not saved.
Is there any simple way to save that list.
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Where is your source code?

Comment: There are diffent possibles approaches depending of what yo need, maybe using the package https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences if it is only for preferences kind
files, or https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite if it would hold more complex data...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use sharedpreferences. First you have to add it as dependency in your pubspec.yaml file. 
More information: https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences